# Place picker close after launch in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

i am integrating Google Place picker in android , but it is closing after launch .

**Code** :

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            Intent intent = builder.build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialogHelper.showAlertDialog(this,e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialogHelper.showAlertDialog(this,e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

**Error**

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/search?key=****************PpdwBIWzGwY
2019-06-20 22:51:08.222 2115-13410/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
2019-06-20 22:51:08.223 2115-13410/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=SearchPlaces
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}]
        at bhjl.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):1)
        at bhjn.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):23)
        at aaha.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):19)
        at bjyv.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):2)
        at smu.b(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):37)
        at smu.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830):18)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at ssz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455021@17.4.55 (040408-248795830))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

**Google API Console**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Configuration looks ok as per documentation , please don't mark it as Duplicate , this is strange issue ,

Comment: Are you sure the package name is right ? Did you build your APK in debug or release ?

Comment: yes,,,,,,, i tried in both debug and release not working .

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).

Place Picker is going to be turned off soon and it's already deprecated.

> IMPORTANT: The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This
>   feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be
>   available after that date. To continue using the Place Picker through
>   the deprecation period, do NOT disable the Places SDK for Android
>   service in your Google Cloud Platform project, as doing so will also
>   disable the Place Picker.